# MPlayer grabs grey image from MTS video

Tags: mplayer

I need to grab a frame from the MTS file at a specified interval of time by the MPlayer.

When I use the **-ss** parameter I get the grey image with random gray squares:

```
mplayer.exe -frames 1 -ss 3 -vo jpeg:quality=95 -vf scale=480:270 test.MTS
```

[image]

However I get the good quality video frame when I omit the **-ss** parameter:

```
mplayer.exe -frames 1 -vo jpeg:quality=95 -vf scale=480:270 test.MTS
```

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to extract the quality video frame from the below video file using the **-ss** parameter?
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2dqufejwkv07fk0/AAC16zUAW_GFbFdvVIMSGyPZa/00001.%5B2%5D.MTS?dl=0

Comment: Put the ss parameter **after** test.MTS and try. At least that is what I would try in ffmpeg. Not very sure about mplayer.exe.

Comment: Rajib, unfortunately it didn't help.